# I wrote this in prolog:

Tags: prolog

```
clauses 
    executa('1'):-
       write("Name:"),readln(NumeP).
```

And I got this Warning: The variable "NumeP" is only used once.

what I can do to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2):

You are reading a line from the prompt and storing it in a "variable" named NumeP, yet, you never use this variable. Could you give more context to your code ?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: use the variable more than once.

The longer answer is that the compiler flags such **singleton variables** as a warning or an error as it's an indication of a probably logic error or typo. Prolog variables by their nature are local in scope: variables that are only every referenced once are useless. To fix it, you can:

- Use the anonymous variable (`_`), or
- Use the variable more than once.

In your case, there's not much point in reading a line of text from the console if all you're going to do with it is throw it away.